# Attempting to Extrude Imported SVG Curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, extrude

I am attempting to extrude a logo that has been imported from an SVG file. The SVG file was made in Adobe Illustrator. I deleted many extraneous layers (at this point, curves) upon import to have just a few main layers.

However, I then desired to extrude this, either through a solidify modifier, or the extrude option in the curves panel. Whichever I try, the result is the same: even if the thickness is 0.1, the shape will go off into infinity for the extrusion.

It appears that the vertices are fine and there are no duplicate/overlapping ones (but please check me), and so I have no idea what could be causing this! This is the first time I've ever tried importing an SVG like this to use, so any pointers are welcomed!

showing extrusion off to infinity with settings
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD9ec.jpg
[image]
File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ijsxQTdUhXQnFqYXNGN1VlRnM/view?usp=sharing

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: This has been asked countless times before, possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes/49980#49980 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/47220#47220 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47825/extruding-vector-files-in-blender/47829#47829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is very very small and has a very large scale.

1. Select all your imported curves and apply scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Scale
2. Join them all together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (select them all and then make sure you click-select at least one last curve to make it the active object, so it will act as receiving curve other curves will be appended to)
3. Now enter edit mode in the new curve
4. Select all vertex and press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>
5. Search for `Set Curve Radius`
6. Enter a value of `1.0`and press enter

You should now be able to extrude successfully
You can now separate all curves again into their original parts by entering edit mode, selecting each spline individually and pressing <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate*

Just a side note, when using curves always prefer the builtin extrusion method over solidify, it is more reliable and has better features like allowing non destructive beveling

Comment: please flag the duplicates so that you don't have to re-write the answer over and over. Use close and select duplicate of...

Comment: please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Comment: and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/506/should-duplicates-be-closed-to-the-oldest-question-or-the-best-question and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/435/1853

Comment: I have seen the other answers before I posted here, but it will not allow me to join my curves, so I thought it was a different question. Basically, I'm stuck at step 2 on the answer above :/

Comment: Joining in Blender uses the active object as "receiving" object the other curves will be appended to. How are you selecting them all, border select? Make sure you click-select at least one last curve (possibly the largest one) to make it the active object so it will receive the other objects, then you can press Ctrl+J to actually join them. Just one note I just fixed the keyboard shortcut for step one, it was wrong.

Comment: For some reason, the lightning bolt still wouldn't cooperate, but everything else did! I just traced over the lightning bolt since it was such a small part and made a new mesh (plane; added vertices; extruded). Thank you for clearing up everything for me! Big help! :)