# Convert Curve (SVG) to Blender exact imperial units

Tags: units, measurement, svg

As a test, I've created a 2D box in Inkscape with the dimensions 1' by 1' (Inkscape shows that 1' is 1080.000px).

I import the SVG into Blender, and when observing the dimensions of the curve converted to mesh, I see that they're not exactly 1' by 1'.

I know that 0.3048 BU is 1 foot.

Does this have anything to do with DPI/PPI? Ideally, I would like to have 1px be one inch in Blender (when converted to a mesh).

Is this possible?

Comment: After many experiments I never found a proper or reliable way to convert SVG units into Blender Scene units. Best I could come up with was to surround my whole SVG drawing with a large rectangle big enough to totally encompass all elements, and with known rounded value dimensions (say 10 x 10 inches). Then after importing I can easily resize the imported drawing to correct scale by using said rectangle as reference.

Comment: Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56501/attempting-to-extrude-imported-svg-curve/56502#56502 for cleanup procedures after rescaling