# SVG repair/editing in Blender

Tags: modeling, text-object, svg

Hey guys I have a question about SVG to blender. I have been having a good deal of success with exception for the letter Z in the particular font that someone chose.

I am able to see the curves and outline when in x-ray mode but when I go to Edit mode it comes out all wrong. I would appreciate any suggestion to help me out to get it modeled, thanks guys.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Either the curve is simply too complex for Blender's triangulator to fill, or there are overlapping vertex, duplicated segments, self intersecting splines somewhere in there, or all of the above.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56501/attempting-to-extrude-imported-svg-curve

Comment: Hey thank you for that info, I started to delete some of the vertices that I thought might be causing the triangulator to fail and that worked, thanks again.