# Creating an bevel inset on an imported SVG

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to create an insetted bevel on an imported SVG in Blender. I so far have the SVG properly imported, and am applying a 0.02 bevel depth to its geometry, and a 32 resolution to that bevel so that it's smooth.

The only problem with this is that the bevel is looking more like the outside of a sphere rather than what I want it to look like, see images below:

[image]

Is this possible? I'm going to be doing this with **a lot** of completely different SVG's over time, so I'd like to find a *quick* and easy way of doing it.

Possible duplicate of [Extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve), but I'm not having an issue with getting it beveled, I am having an issue with the direction of the bevel.

Here's what my setup looks like in Blender:

[image]

Thanks for all help in advance!

After trying the recommendation below, these are my results:

[image]

And then with it applied to the SVG

[image]

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom bevel curve with the desired shape.

Draw a quarter circle and use as bevel object on the original curve.

[image]

**EDIT**

Upon looking at your file your Bevel curve is waaay too big in relation to your SVG imported curve, its center is incorrectly positioned, and the bevel curve is scaled zero in Z.

Reduce its size in edit mode, and clear its scale. The normals are also inverted, you may also need to *Switch Direction* of your bevel curve in *Edit Mode* to display correctly.

Also your imported SVG is quite complex in shape, with high curvature and very tight corners, it is hard to bevel it correctly, you probably have to accept a certain degree of errors, or be willing to fix them by hand.

[image]

Comment: Noob question, I know, but how did you generate that half circle curve? I just tried making one and it's not working as illustrated.

Comment: It is just a bezier curve circle, handles set to free and erase 3 segments. Be sure to place its the object center at a convenient location

Comment: Please see my updated post. Any chance you could just upload your Blender file with it working and I could see what you did from there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save the file, it was made on the fly. You probably have either a scaled curve, a non 1.0 radius value on your vertex or both. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56501/attempting-to-extrude-imported-svg-curve and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale . Also make sure your bevel object center is correctly placed relative to the geometry.

Comment: I've tried both of those links, but I am not able to reproduce this result yet unfortunately.. I've marked it as the right answer as it certainly is, it's just I'm not accustomed to blender enough yet to take advantage of it it seems, haha.

Comment: Can you share your simplified [file showing the problem](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)? Maybe we can diagnose what is wrong, be sure to include it in your original question and ping me if you do

Comment: Here you go, if I scale the bezier circle, it does start to almost look right, but it glitches.  Also, I need the surface of the SVG to stay the same size after the bevel has been added - [Download the blender file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4020/) @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: It seems you basically ignored all the hints from my comments. You didn't correctly set the curve center, your didn't mind its size nor did any sensible sizing relative to the curve. Answer updated above