# How do i extrude without faces intersecting (inside a cube)

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to make that part of my mesh thicker, and the way i do it (extruding part by part) ends up with the two parts intersecting and i think it'll be a problem in the future.

[image]

here the problem

[image: here the prblem]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good job for [curve bevels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg)