# How do I extrude a shape along a curve in Blender 2.8

Tags: extrude, path

I can't find any posts on how to extrude a shape along a curve in Blender 2.8.

Let's say I wanted to make a curved pipe.
In Blender 2.7 I used 2 curves (1 path and 1 shape). With the path selected, under geometry, I chose the shape as bevel object, and finally converted the result to a mesh.

But in 2.8, I can't figure out how the modifiers work.
I've tried an array modifier combined with a curve modifier, but I can't get it to do anything remotely useful. The bevel modifier doesn't seem to do the trick either. I've tried numerous different combinations of modifiers, but with no luck.

Comment: Hi. Why can't you use the same methods as you used in 2.7?

Comment: I can't find the old options. I figured they changed it all up with these modifiers.

Comment: This is not (either in 2.7) in the modifier part, but in the curve properties.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567#58567 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg/92635#92635

Comment: I just found the geometry tab in 2.8! Thank you so much guys - you truly are lifesavers! :D

Comment: @SigurdKnarhøiJohannsen I suggest adding that as an answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I thought modifiers were the "next generation" geometry tab.

Luckily it turns out I had overlooked that the geometry tab still exists in Blender 2.8!
It's the green triangle icon in the menu on the right hand side of the default layout. (the data tab)

From there on, it's just like in Blender 2.7, as I described in the question.

Thanks for the quick comments to my questions!

Comment: For future reference..just in case you have to look stuff up or get what people are talking about.., the tab is usually referred to as the 'Data' tab.. available for all kinds of objects.. in the case of a Curve, it contains a 'Geometry' panel.