# Importing Adobe SVG cuts off half the image

Tags: bezier-curves, import, svg

how it looks in adobe illustartor

[image]

how it looks in blender

[image]

I've tried several things including expanding the objects, trying to upload parts of it without the others. but it always cuts off the image in the same place.

Here's my SVG file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mWWP7kVeT7ZEF4dXdPZDZjdHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you checked the imported SVG file in a browser or other application and see if t displays correctly? Have you entered edit mode in imported curve? Some times it's just missing a fill because of overlapping vertex but the geometry is actually there. Could you share the SVG file so we can lok at it?

Comment: this as been asked many many times before, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47825/extruding-vector-files-in-blender/47829#47829 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/47220#47220 if it helps

Comment: converting it to a mesh doesnt seem to help
http://screencast.com/t/5kxqIO8tsQQX
whats the best way for me to share the SVG?

Comment: Yep, your SVG file is pretty messed up and has an insane and unnecessary amount of vertex. It doesn't even display right in Inkscape either. Remake it with proper vector vertex topology and it should be fine. Also remove any effects and strokes before exporting, and don't convert to mesh unless strictly necessary

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet for high precision results is to simplify the Paths in Illustrator first, then export as svg. I tried loading that SVG into another vector drawing tool (Inkscape) but the Paths it contains also do not get read/displayed correctly. This doesn't mean the SVG is bad (it loads in Google Chrome just fine), but it does mean the Paths themselves are not optimal for use to interchange between some programs.

Your SVG has a lot of dense areas which Blender's Curve objects don't handle very well. -- (In Blender if you converted to mesh and did a Remove Doubles it would remove about 800 points..) . The linked Answers in the Comments under your question suggest valid reasons why this SVG isn't showing correctly. There are overlapping areas due to the dense clusters of points (Open the SVG in Illustrator and zoom into the area where it cuts off in Blender to see the overlapping edges).

*but* if you have to do it in Blender, then one process is:

- join all curves  (select all curves, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
- convert to mesh  (in Object Mode hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and pick  *Mesh from Curve*)
- remove doubles (in Edit Mode, select all verts, then <kbd>W</kbd> -> *Remove Doubles*
- convert to curve (in Object Mode hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and pick  *Curve from ...*)
- set curve to 2D (In the Curve Tab in Object Properties, to get the fill)
  [image]

then you get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you turn down the curve resolution it works but this isn't always ideal[image: Curve reoolution]