# Blender 2.8 how extrude Z axis on imported SVG

Tags: svg

I am using blender 2.8 and I imported an SVG file and was able to convert it into a mesh. I used mesh clean up -> limited dissolve to remove extra vertices. I would now like to extrude my object on the Z axis but it will not occur.

Reading older posts, on older version of Blender, seems to indicate I need to modify something to allow Z axis extrusion. but I am not sure where to go in the UI to modify that property?

Answer (score 0):

ok, at the very bottom of this, helped answer my question.
[Extrude on Z axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80811/extrude-on-z-axis)

"Also make sure you "apply scale" (CTRL+A) to make extruding work as expected. "