# How can I Extrude Objects According to Their Colors?

Tags: python, import, color, extrude

I am Now making a model for an electrical component (Arduino) , I have an svg image for it , I inserted the image to Blender and I now want to extrude it to be 3D, but I do not want to extrude every object Manualy  .. I want to extrude object by colors.

This is the image :

[image]

Note :-

- I do not want to use a material which give a 3D Shape
- I Want this Via Anything Python,Blender....

This How It looks After importing :

[image]

[Its not Seen Clearly visible  because many objects are in the same position]

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you please show how it looks after importing to Blender and converting to mesh?

Comment: Svg is not an image...

Comment: @LukeD I added an image.

Comment: what you have above imho are several objects of "curve" type (importing from svg gives curves). Each separate "curve" will have a basic material color like in the svg.You cannot extrude curves. You have to convert them to "mesh" objects. Then imho you can select each object by their rgb colors, and extrude them  accordingly. Manually or by python script.

Comment: @m.ardito I Converted To mesh , And Now i want to extrude it. How?

Comment: @m.ardito you *can* extrude curves, and you should not be destructively converting to mesh unless needed. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47825/extruding-vector-files-in-blender

Comment: ...yes, true, sorry :) but, anyway, I would work with real mesh in this case. It's quite detailed and I would like to have mesh tools available (uvmap, eg)... I see no particular benefit here to keep them curves tbh.

Comment: see this as a primer for blender python scripting https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/info_overview.html

Comment: about converting to mesh, I said that because I guessed you wish to obtain something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQHRw.jpg and maybe add decals and textures to replicate the real thing. This is impossible with just curves, I fear, but quite easy with meshes. I would learn to do it manually first, then try to automate a "perfect" workflow learning blender python scripting...

Answer (score 3):

There may be a good answer within Blender.  But if you just need to get the job done, you could open your SVG file in Inkscape.  Inkscape has the ability to select objects by the same colors, e.g. select one object with the desired color and choose "Edit --> Select Same --> Fill Color".  In this way you could create several SVG files, each containing only objects of the same color.  You can then import each SVG file separately and give each one a group, so that you can select and edit the group easily.

I did this with a circuit board SVG (a two-dimensional one) I found online with the following results:

[image: circuit board render]

The curves can indeed be extruded without converting to meshes, simply modify the "Extrude" value under "Modification" in the "Geometry" section of the curve data tab.  If you want to set all the extrude values at once, join the curves first.  This is a good reason for keeping them as curves for as long as possible, btw.