# SVG from illustrator doesnt fill correctly

Tags: svg

Blender is not filling correctly the SVG file imported from illustrator even after trying all the options for SVG exporting on illustrator. On the attached photo, you can see the area referred with the blue arrow doesn't fill until I delete the red areas.

The filling before deleting the red areas:

[image: The filling before deleting the red areas]

The filling after deleting the red areas:

[image: The filling after deleting the red areas]

Would you please help me sort this out?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/47220#47220 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47825/extruding-vector-files-in-blender/47829#47829

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you for your comment but my SVG file doesnt have intersected / overlapped curves. I have already combined them into one path in illustrator.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Looking at your second link... Yes there have been some overlapping nodes and some weirdly oriented handles. I have smoothed some areas out. everything is okay now. Thank you!