# My Blender SVG imports are a mess

Tags: extrude, svg

I have folder of SVG files looking something like this:

[image]

I want to extrude these into solid meshes.

I import the .svg file as a 2D curve. It was prepared in
Inkscape with a union operation; That is to say, it is a single curve object.

[image]

As we see, paths are missed and the filled and open region are confused.
This phenomenon is seen at every setting of curve resolution in Blender.

Is something wrong with the .svg file?
Here is the result of the operation carried out in my "toy" 3D modeler, Cheetah3D.
[image]

Not a problem!

Suggestions for more reliable SVG import settings in Blender would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47825/extruding-vector-files-in-blender/47829 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill/75736 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875