# Path Curve Deform creates unprintable non-manifold geometry

Tags: bezier-curves

I created an SVG vector mesh in illustrator, imported it to Blender and used it as a path to deform a triangle along. It makes a design that I rather like. Unfortunately when I convert that path to mesh, it is unprintable due to the ways the geometry doubles over itself at each vertice[image]. Blender's 3D printing tools delete or destroy the mesh when I try to fix it. What are the keys to using path deform without creating overlapping or self-intersecting geometry? The finished form is meant to be 3D printed. Thanks for any help you might have. I have tried other mesh-fixers to fix the non-manifold issues and none of them work. I have also tried using path deform with dozens of different checked boxes and still no luck. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Is it possible for you to [upload your file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) with your object *before* it is converted to mesh? The problem *could* be easier to solve before conversion. Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve