# Weird spikes when bevel

Tags: extrude, bevel

[image]

I'm having troubles when trying to add a bevel to an extruded svg, anybody know why this is happening? Totally new to blender and still have little to none experience in Blender / 3d software.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This usually happens due to the topology of the object you are beveling, try to reduce the bevel amount.

Comment: It is already on the lowest value of 0.001 i cant reduce it anymore. And still, there must be a way to get a desired bevel without this nasty spike right?

Comment: Likely svg was imported with some double vertices / wrongly filled areas. Try doing clean-up for it either in vector application or on imported in Blender. If in Blender see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve

Comment: A limitation of blenders curve drawing. Adjust the extrude/offset values until it works right. Adjusting the points in the curve where it goes weird may also work. It is often only tiny adjustments that make the difference in these situations.

Comment: Select all vertices in edit mode and press space and type remove doubles. In the "T" menu you can change the distance until some vertices are removed. This might help.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89898/spike-when-trying-to-add-bevel

Comment: can you share the blend file so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting "Clamp Overlap" in the Geometry settings. It fixed a spike problem for me.