# Weird spikes when bevel extruded svg

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude, bevel

I am trying to give some depth to my svg files. I have imported an svg file and then joined the curves together by grouping them. The extruding it self does not give any problems, however when i try to give it a bevel or adjust the offset these weird spikes stick out my object. Also, even though I joined the objects together i still can't extrude them all together. Am I doing the grouping wrong?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered

Comment: thanks for your answer but as i mentioned above, being the noob that i am i still can't seem to find out what's wrong even with looking at the post you mentioned.

Comment: Then a project file could be the best way for others to see what's wrong with it on earth. You can try updating it [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then paste the link back.