# Transforming a paper-like model into a 3d model

Tags: modeling

I recently started using Blender this morning and I got up all the way to this point:
[image: Model of a character's torso]

But I didn't realize that it was flat (almost like a paper as shown in the image), I first concluded that I could probably change it's thickness later on in the making.
[image: View at how flat it is]

I tried using Solidify but it distorted the model, a lot.
[image: Distorted torso]

Is there anyway I can make the model thicker without having to redo it from the start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extruded SVG showing spikes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get front, back, top, bottom, left, and right reference images of things and making them background images with `N panel` <kbd>N</kbd> > `Background Images`. Make a 2D mesh for each reference and then try to combine them together to make a 3D mesh. I cannot tell you how exactly because it will vary with each model, but I can tell you that you can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join the meshes and try to combine the appropriate vertices, and then fill in the faces.

I did this for a hawk's beak recently. What I did was that I made the side reference mesh, duplicated and made them 45 degrees apart (the front reference showed this), joined and connected them and made faces, applied a subsurf modifier, and it looked like an actual beak. So that tells you that this technique works. There are other methods, though!

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the faces in edit mode and use 'E' to extrude the faces. Though this will only give you an extruded model like play-doh. If you're trying to recreate the model in 3D properly, you're going to have to learn polygonal modeling.