# Points of vector in from .svg file imported to Blender become squished when imported

Tags: mesh, import, svg

I have been running into an issue with importing .svg files into Blender. I created a vector shown below in Illustrator and saved it as an SVG 1.1 with all base settings. I then try to import it into Blender with File > Import > .svg but every time the points that make up the X's of the eyes become distorted or squished. I am just confused that it is only the eyes that are messing up.

**Edit 1**

This issue is not like this question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered), because I am not intentionally wanting my vectors squished to the side nor am I having trouble extruding the svg once imported. The problem I am stuck with is the fact that I want the X's of the eyes to be imported correctly and not squished above and outside of the main circle.

**Edit 2**

This issue is also not like the questions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve). That is because these two problems are dealing with extruding and already imported .svg file. I problem I am experiencing is that my .svg file is not importing into my scene correctly as shown by pictures 2 and 3. I DO NOT want the two X's shown in picture 1 to be squished outside of the circle. I want them to import the exact same way as they are shown in picture 1.

---

**[Here](https://www.filedropper.com/smile2-01) is the .svg file.**

I really do appreciate all the help I have received with this question so far, however, none of the suggested duplicates are similar to the issue I am experiencing.

---

**(Picture 1)**
[image: Vector in Illustrator]

**(Picture 2)**
[image: Resulting Curves in Blender]

**(Picture 3)**
[image: Second Version of Resulting Curves in Blender]

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG Curve Incorrectly Rendered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered)

Comment: Can you add a copy of the svg in question so others can test?

Comment: Yes! My apologies. Adding it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extruded SVG showing spikes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve