# What cause these artifacts in 3D text?

Tags: text-object, artifacts

I've attached an image below of artifacting that happens with 3D text when you push the 'depth' parameter to extremes.  The artifacts look as if a vertex on the letters has been pulled out really far resulting in large spikes.

I want to understand why this is happening because

1. I would like to know how to fix this issue
2. If I ever wanted to use this effect for stylistic purposes I want to know how to recreate it.

[image: 3D Text in Blender]

Thanks!

Comment: I guess these are extruded vertices that follow their direction?

Comment: Your depth is too high. Try turning it down.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes/49980#49980