What is the best way to import SVG text and extrude without random n-gons?

Why does text always do this? Is there way to import SVG text in a cleaner way? This causes problems while extruding and smoothing.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion/56352#56352 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/extruded-svg-showing-spikes/49980#49980

Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Hello, and thanks for your comment.
I did do a preliminary search, but I'm not well versed enough in Blender to understand or know that what I'm looking for has something to do with "curve extrusion". In any case, will look at the links you shared, thanks!

See if the links help, otherwise you can edit your post and clarify what you are still stuck with. editing it will automatically queue it up for review.
