# Curve vs. Mesh modeling

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I am working on a tree-like structure that could be created by either a mesh object or a series of bezier curves. Assuming that I can create the object either way, what are the pros and cons of modeling with curves vs. a mesh with respect to routine things like shading, texturing, uv mapping, rendering, etc.?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71640/modeling-with-curves-coming-from-c4d/71660#71660

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the picture of the object you are trying to model?

One of the cons of using curves that i experienced is you cannot make the thickness randomized or uneven.. like in branches of a tree they are not the same thickness throughout. so by using curves you cannot achieve the same thing..

Comment: I don't think this is true. You can use a separate, uneven curve as the bevel profile to get uneveness.

Comment: Oh I didn't know we could do that.. If you don't mind sir Can you please show us. I have been using blender since a few months 6 maybe.. Im not an expert myself. I'd like to see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tree add-on that adds a tree-like *curve* into the scene. You can edit the leaves, branches, trunk, everything from a menu. If you want it as a mesh, you can right-click and convert it to a mesh when you are done and make further changes.