# How do I create faces between curves?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, faces

(I'm on the far side of 50 so please forgive me if this is blatantly apparent to the younger generations!)

Hopefully simple question. I am trying my hand at modeling in Blender for the first time and I am running into an issue. This likely has an answer already somewhere but as with many newcomers to a realm I lack the jargon, lingo and technical wisdom to know the right words to search or questions to ask. So here it goes...

I am trying to model a Glock pistol as a starting project that seemed to be a good mix of both simple shapes requiring the full-breadth of tools and sculpting options. To start I have created paths around a side-on picture of a Glock in Inkscape and imported the .svg file to get me the lines needed to create the shapes. I have converted all of them to 'Mesh from Curve' (using Blender 2.82.7) Now I am trying to create faces between these curves and I can't seem to find the right option/setting. Also running head-long into the jargon issue as I am sure this is a fairly easy answer.

[image]

Comment: As this is a 3D software I wouldn't recommend this way to model the object as a whole. Curves are good for profiles, rotating object pipes etc. If I understand you want to fill the shape with faces and then extrude it to third dimension. You will have a hard time to actually work with the model later on. The sculpting is not that good for hard surface models as well. I would recommend to model the gun by pieces as it is made of from basic shapes as cubes and add details on them.

Comment: For an example here is a speeded video of some futuristic colt modeling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz_tylZqfLw

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71640/modeling-with-curves-coming-from-c4d/71660#71660