# Drawing/editing spline shapes. How?

Tags: modeling, splines

I have been using 3DS Max for years in my profession as an exhibition designer, I use extruding spline shapes quite often.

A simple example would be drawing a rectangle to the size I need and extrude to the height needed. This obviously went into more complex shapes with rounded edges etc. I find it easy to create custom walls and shapes that way. Is there something like that in Blender? I have looked but the curve tool is nowhere near as precise and starting with a plane and editing it misses functions such as offset etc.

I know I should use poly modelling or something, but speed is important to me and the spline way is very fast and precise for me. Is there a way to use it in Blender or a plugin I could use?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71640/modeling-with-curves-coming-from-c4d/71660 Also see https://blender-addons.org/flexi-bezier-tool