# Problem extruding from beveled curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am a total noob trying to do a tutorial - to make a neon sign. Here's a link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQjQfmjDXXA

Basically, you convert text to "curve from mesh/text," then go to "curve > shape > fill (none)" and then "geometry > bevel." So at this point, you have grey tubes. They are doubles, so to get single tubes, you have to select points in each letter and "x > delete > segments." Then delete the parts you don't want. Now you have single tube letters.

Here's my problem: The next step is to select vertices on the letters to extrude back - to get a 3D neon geometry. I am getting weird artifacts on my "U" letters (flickering). When I go to extrude, they extrude weird droopy extrusions (see attached). Other letters extrude straight and correct. I have tried deleting the "tops" of the "U" and reconstructing by extruding up from the lower part of the "U" and I get the same result each time. Any ideas what is causing this baggy distorted geometry?

Thank you for your help and patience with a beginner trying to learn!

[image]

Comment: It seems as though there are double vertices in the U - or the vertices are upside down? I tried to convert to mesh and the flickering was still there - and when I added a solidify modifier the whole end ballooned up. Not sure how to fix this geometry

Comment: Try messing around with the scale of the handle. It really looks like that artifact when theres two meshes on the same coordinates on an axis. Blender is trying to render both at once, and you get that.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/47220#47220

Comment: Thank you Corbomite and Duarte Farrajota Ramos!