# Extrude shape on a path from illustrator?

Tags: extrude, bezier-curves

I have an illustrator path that I want to bring into Blender3d and extrude a circle on and close the shape at the ends. Almost like a long skinny balloon that is used for balloon animals. Or a tube with rounded closed ends. Is it possible to bring a path in from illustrator (It is a company's logo basically) and extrude a path along it as described prior? If so how would I go about it? tia.

Updated with an image. So far I have not figured out how to get my illustrator path into Blender to be able to extrude from. The blue line is the path I am trying to import. The stroke thickness applied is to illustrate the effect I am after but I of course and wanting it in 3d with rounded end caps.[image: illustrator vector path]

Comment: hello, please show some pictures of what you want, share your logo or at least something that is closed to your logo

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+extrude+along+path+from+illustrator There is quite a lot out there. If you need something more specific update your question with images and what you have tried.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/47227#47227

Comment: @moonboots I added a picture to hopefully clarify what I am after

Comment: Try this out, similar concept if you place the stepped circles together and try object > blend > replace spine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcBBDN8PKqU&t=117s&ab_channel=GraphicDesignHowTo