# bevel outer edge from curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, extrude

I have a curve shape converted to mesh and extruded, and now I want to bevel the perimeter. However, the bevel ends up messing up at certain places and I do not know why. Why one bunny ear and not the other? Why one point and not the other? I looked at a few different [answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve) that said make sure your curves are clean, and I believe mine are. [image]Thank you so much! [image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can set **Bevel** also for **Curve** object type under *Object Data Properties > Geometry* > **Extrude** and under **Bevel** > *Depth* ...

[image]

In extreme corners it has its issues, but could be working in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

You have a messy topology that will prevent any good bevel.

Once you have converted to mesh, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. In the *Operator box* choose a *Max Angle* value around 5°:

[image]

Create these edges at the bottom of the ears, clean a bit at the tip of the right ear:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Now the bevel works well, maybe it will need some correction at the tip of the ear, depending on the width:

[image]

Comment: this works great! why did you add those edges at the base of the ears though? it seems to work without doing that and just fixing the one ear so I'm just curious!

Comment: from what I remember the bevel bugged if I didn't