# How to make something like this with cuts in circle border in Blender?

Tags: modeling, 2d

I am new to Blender and trying hard to design a 2D image into 3D
I am able to make the lines in center but don't know how to make this circle with cuts in border where lines are cutting

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Do you already have your design as an SVG file? You might be able to follow this method to extrude the SVG logo/image into a 3D object. [Extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve#:~:text=Because%20.svg%20imports%20into%20Blender%20as%20a%20curve,you%20can%20modify%20the%20object%20however%20you%20wish)

Comment: I already tried doing that but there are too many extra vertices and edges everywhere and it all going in wrong manner and it visually very wrong.