# Random spikes with the Antique Roman font

Tags: bevel, text-object, font

So I noticed a very niche problem when using an Antique Roman font that causes random spike to jut out of letters when using a round bevel of any depth. Is there any way to get around this (I'm trying to outline letters)[image]

It happens with more letters than just the M, H, E, and M, but you get the point.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve

Answer (score 2):

Bevel geometry doesn't work great with fonts that have jagged edges such as the one you're using. I suggest that you use a different font. This problem has been discussed before [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/77822). I experimented with the same font and got the same result. However, I did find that changing the Resolution Preview amount, under the Shape drop-down in the Data tab, helps with reducing the spikes but, not 100%.

If you look closely at the font in wireframe view, you can see points where the edges make loops and it is at those points that the spikes jut out of as well as any really sharp corners. So, maybe cleaning up the geometry after converting it to a regular mesh could help.

[image]