Text Solidify not working for letters "t" and "f"
I'm trying to add text to my bases.  Worked fine till I used the letters "f" and "t" where it has some additional raised surface.  Looks espicially bad with the shrinkwrap modifier, but I narrowed down the problem to when I try to solidify text.  Switching the font doesn't help.  Any thoughts?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/
